# Restrict image blob size to less than 2 MB in appscript sheet application

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to restrict an image blob size to less than 2 MB. I am currently making an app with google sheets, to be used in mobiles or tabs, which enables you to capture an image after selecting a cell in sheets

Thereby,I need to place the captured image in the cell as well as store in google drive

I am using insertImage() function in appscript to place the image in the selected cell, but apparently it is restricted to blob size less than 2MB.Following is my code.

```
function uploadFile(fileObject) {
    
     var link=[],file_extension=[],fileName=[];
     var folderID=getIdFromUrl(fileObject["folderURL"]);
     var imageName=fileObject["imageName"];
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
     for(var k=0;k<fileObject["file"]["name"].length;k++){
       var splitBase = fileObject["file"]["content"][k].split(','),
         type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');
       
       var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
       var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, 'image/png', imageName);
       ss.setName(imageName);
       var file = folder.createFile(ss);
      file_extension.push(fileObject["file"]["name"][k].substring(fileObject["file"]["name"][k].lastIndexOf(".")+1));
      link.push(file.getUrl());
     
      }
    
     var response = {
      'link':link,
      'extension':file_extension,
     }
     fileObject["file"]["response"]=response;

    var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var act=sheet.getActiveCell();
   
    var ssActiveCellRow=act.getRow();
    var ssActiveCellCol=act.getColumn();

    sheet.insertImage(ss, ssActiveCellCol,ssActiveCellRow);
    return fileObject;
   }
```

Comment: Restrict it client side.

Answer (score 0):

### Class Blob has getBytes() method

In order to restrict the image you can handle it by making some previous calculation like the following:

```
...
var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, 'image/png', imageName);
var blobSize = ss.getBytes().length / 1024**2; // Which is Bytes to MBytes
if (blobsize < 2) {
   // Insert image
}
...
```

Or you can just compare the number of bytes

```
...
var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, 'image/png', imageName);
var blobSize = ss.getBytes().length;
if (blobsize < 2097152) {
   // Insert image
}
...
```

### References

- [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)
- [Blob.getBytes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getbytes)